# How to get the middle of text of a cell in spreadsheet?

Tags: spreadsheet

I am working on a spreadsheet and cleaning up the data. I learned about the LEFT and RIGHT functions, i.e. =LEFT(D2,10) query for the left of a text string and =RIGHT(D2,8) query for the right of a text string. What is the name for the query to capture the middle of a text in a cell?

I tried to just delete the cells by hand, but I had too many entries so I'd like a code to make it faster.

Comment: For middle text or any portion use `substring`. ... Note that your question lacks proper tags. But the function names you did mention appear to be "VB" so assuming you are using Excel.